# Handling deserialization of a JSON field of polymorphic type (String or Int)

Tags: android, json, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

Our API returns a `reserved_stock` field that can be either a String or an Int (i.e. "158" or "5"). Since I cannot alter the API's response directly, I have to figure out a way to handle both types.

What would be the right way to do this using Kotlinx.Serialization? As of right now, I have tried declaring the field as a sealed class type and then use a custom Serializer to decode the actual value. Something along the lines of:

```
@Serializable(with = ReservedStockSerializer::class)
sealed class ReservedStock {
    @Serializable
    data class IntValue(val value: Int) : ReservedStock()
    @Serializable
    data class StringValue(val value: String) : ReservedStock()
}

@Serializable
object ReservedStockSerializer : KSerializer<ReservedStock> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("ReservedStock", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: ReservedStock) {
        val stringRepresentation = when (value) {
            is ReservedStock.IntValue -> value.value.toString()
            is ReservedStock.StringValue -> value.value
        }
        encoder.encodeString(stringRepresentation)
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): ReservedStock {
        val composite = decoder.beginStructure(descriptor)
        var intValue: Int? = null
        var stringValue: String? = null

        loop@ while (true) {
            when (val index = composite.decodeElementIndex(descriptor)) {
                CompositeDecoder.DECODE_DONE -> break@loop
                else -> {
                    when (index) {
                        0 -> intValue = composite.decodeIntElement(descriptor, index)
                        1 -> stringValue = composite.decodeStringElement(descriptor, index)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        composite.endStructure(descriptor)

        return if (intValue != null) {
            ReservedStock.IntValue(intValue)
        } else {
            ReservedStock.StringValue(stringValue ?: "")
        }
    }
}
```

This does not seem to work however, since it throws a JsonException stating that it was expecting an object but instead found an Int (or String).

Comment: I suggest trying [JsonTransformingSerializer](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-json/kotlinx.serialization.json/-json-transforming-serializer/)

Comment: @Pawel That seems to have worked. I'm gonna post my trivial implementation below so if you find any errors in my logic, feel free to correct me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it work, i had to specify `isLenient=true` in the JsonConfig since our API returns unquoted values.

I also created the following trivial `JsonTransformingSerializer`, like so:

```
object ReservedStockSerializer : JsonTransformingSerializer<String>(String.serializer()) {
    override fun transformDeserialize(element: JsonElement): JsonElement {
        return if(element !is JsonPrimitive) JsonPrimitive("N/A") else element
    }
}
```

and applied it to the field in question like so:

```
...
@Serializable(ReservedStockSerializer::class)
@SerialName("reserved_stock")
val reservedStock: String,
...
```